# caffe loss error: Check failed: The data and label should have the same first dimension

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

Here is my blob shapes and layers:

-------------------------------- blobs

```
data                        4096     4.10e+03    (1, 2, 1, 2048)
Convolution1               32736     3.27e+04    (1, 16, 1, 2046)
ReLU1                      32736     3.27e+04    (1, 16, 1, 2046)
Convolution2               32704     3.27e+04    (1, 16, 1, 2044)
ReLU2                      32704     3.27e+04    (1, 16, 1, 2044)
...
Crop4                       4224     4.22e+03    (1, 16, 1, 264)
Concat4                     8448     8.45e+03    (1, 32, 1, 264)
Convolution17               4192     4.19e+03    (1, 16, 1, 262)
ReLU21                      4192     4.19e+03    (1, 16, 1, 262)
Convolution18               4160     4.16e+03    (1, 16, 1, 260)
unet1                       4160     4.16e+03    (1, 16, 1, 260)
ampl0                       4096     4.10e+03    (1, 4096)
Reshape0                    4096     4.10e+03    (1, 1, 1, 4096)
conv1                      65472     6.55e+04    (1, 16, 1, 4092)
conv1_conv1_0_split_0      65472     6.55e+04    (1, 16, 1, 4092)
conv1_conv1_0_split_1      65472     6.55e+04    (1, 16, 1, 4092)
Scale1                     65472     6.55e+04    (1, 16, 1, 4092)
ReLU22                     65472     6.55e+04    (1, 16, 1, 4092)
Scale2                     65472     6.55e+04    (1, 16, 1, 4092)
...
ReLU28                    517120     5.17e+05    (1, 128, 8, 505)
Scale8                    517120     5.17e+05    (1, 128, 8, 505)
ReLU29                    517120     5.17e+05    (1, 128, 8, 505)
crelu4                   1034240     1.03e+06    (1, 128, 16, 505)
maxPool4                  518144     5.18e+05    (1, 128, 16, 253)
ampl                          21     2.10e+01    (1, 21)
```

The error I get in loss layer:

```
F0416 15:43:21.957676 95620 loss_layer.cpp:19] Check failed: bottom[0]->shape(0) == bottom[1]->shape(0) (1 vs. 10) The data and label should have the same first dimension.
```

Note: The error appeared after I added a fully connected layer (ampl0) + Reshape (Reshape0) layer in the middle of CNN layers. without them it works just fine!

Thanks for your help.
**Update:** Those fully connected and Reshape layers are:

```
layer {
  name: "ampl0"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "unet1"
  top: "ampl0"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    bias_term: false
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "Reshape0"
  type: "Reshape"
  bottom: "ampl0"
  top: "Reshape0"
  reshape_param {
    shape {
      dim: 1
      dim: 1
      dim: 1
      dim:-1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where is "label" blob? what are its dimensions? what layer emits this error? what are the shapes of the input blobs for this layer? If you can answer these questions clearly I am sure you'll have an answer to your question.

Comment: so I had a conventional 8 layer CNN that works fine. I added a "InnerProduct" layer (and Reshape layer) after 4th layer. Data and Label layers are the same, so their dimensions. nothing else (in theory) has changed!

Comment: I updated those added layers to the main question

Comment: so finally I am making some progress. my batch_size was 10. when I change it to 1 everything is OK! any idea why this is happening?
thats why Check failed: bottom[0]->shape(0) == bottom[1]->shape(0) (1 vs. 10) was happening ...

Comment: your reshape layer forces batch size to be one. try using axis:0 on the conv1 params instead of reshape

Comment: but then I have a pooling layer error:
Check failed: 4 == bottom[0]->num_axes() (4 vs. 2) Input must have 4 axes, corresponding to (num, channels, height, width)

Comment: ok. then make reshape layer ignore the first dimension

Comment: this means I will again have batch_size =1 problem?

Comment: no. if reshpe properly ignore the first dimension then it does not change it and you should be good for any batch size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`"Reshape"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/reshape.html) layer forces the first dimension (`batch_size`) to be 1, thus when you change the `batch_size` your net breaks.
To avoid that, you need `"Reshape"` to *copy* the first dimension:

```
  layer {
    name: "reshape"
    type: "Reshape"
    bottom: "input"
    top: "output"
    reshape_param {
      shape {
        dim: 0  # copy the dimension from below  <-- !!
        dim: 1  # insert singleton dimension
        dim: 1
        dim: -1 # infer it from the other dimensions
      }
    }
  }
```

I suppose

```
    reshape_param { shape { dim: 1 dim: 1 }  num_axes: 0 axis: 1 }
```

Might also pull the trick for you.

For more information and options about `"Reshape"` params, see [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L1024-L1086):

> ```
>   // axis and num_axes control the portion of the bottom blob's shape that are
>   // replaced by (included in) the reshape. By default (axis == 0 and
>   // num_axes == -1), the entire bottom blob shape is included in the reshape,
>   // and hence the shape field must specify the entire output shape.
>   //
>   // axis may be non-zero to retain some portion of the beginning of the input
>   // shape (and may be negative to index from the end; e.g., -1 to begin the
>   // reshape after the last axis, including nothing in the reshape,
>   // -2 to include only the last axis, etc.).
>   //
>   // For example, suppose "input" is a 2D blob with shape 2 x 8.
>   // Then the following ReshapeLayer specifications are all equivalent,
>   // producing a blob "output" with shape 2 x 2 x 4:
>   //
>   //   reshape_param { shape { dim: 2  dim: 2  dim: 4 } }
>   //   reshape_param { shape { dim: 2  dim: 4 } axis:  1 }
>   //   reshape_param { shape { dim: 2  dim: 4 } axis: -3 }
>   //
>   // num_axes specifies the extent of the reshape.
>   // If num_axes >= 0 (and axis >= 0), the reshape will be performed only on
>   // input axes in the range [axis, axis+num_axes].
>   // num_axes may also be -1, the default, to include all remaining axes
>   // (starting from axis).
>   //
>   // For example, suppose "input" is a 2D blob with shape 2 x 8.
>   // Then the following ReshapeLayer specifications are equivalent,
>   // producing a blob "output" with shape 1 x 2 x 8.
>   //
>   //   reshape_param { shape { dim:  1  dim: 2  dim:  8 } }
>   //   reshape_param { shape { dim:  1  dim: 2  }  num_axes: 1 }
>   //   reshape_param { shape { dim:  1  }  num_axes: 0 }
>   //
>   // On the other hand, these would produce output blob shape 2 x 1 x 8:
>   //
>   //   reshape_param { shape { dim: 2  dim: 1  dim: 8  }  }
>   //   reshape_param { shape { dim: 1 }  axis: 1  num_axes: 0 }
>   //
> ```